# How to change view by controller and action even if that is root path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a decorator that changes behaivior by controller and action like this:

```
class ShortPositionDecorator < ApplicationDecorator
  delegate_all
  def company_short_name
    return if h.current_page?(action: 'positions', controller: 'users')
    object.company.short_name
  end
end
```

This is the route for it.

```
get 'positions', to: 'users#positions'
```

But when I use the route as a root path,

#### config/routes.rb

```
root 'users#positions'
```

I had to add a condition for root path.

```
 def company_short_name
   return if h.current_page?(action: 'positions', controller: 'users')
+  return if h.current_page?('/') 
   object.company.short_name
 end
```

Is there a way to change view by action and controller even if the path is `/`?

If I use `current_page?('/')`, I must change several places for just changing the root path. I want to avoid that kind of mess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`controller_name` and `action_name`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters) to get the current controller/action and create a custom helper:

```
def current_controller_action?(controller:,action:)
  controller == controller_name && action == action_name
end
```

and use that instead of `current_page?`...a quick look at [the source for `current_page?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F) shows that it calls `url_for` and passes in what you passed to it, so multiple routes in your routes file pointing at the same controller/action aren't going to work well with it.